# Rename Account Detail Label near buttons and Custom auto number field

Tags: account, auto-number

1. I want to rename Account Detail to Vendor Detail and not change the tab label.
2. Also, there is auto number field on account, I want to rename it. And I cannot seem to find this field to rename in Rename tabs and label setup menu.
   Please suggest.

Thanks!

Comment: let me know if my answer works for you

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I want to rename Account Detail to Vendor Detail and not change the tab label.

This can be done by this:

[image: rename account]

> 2. Also, there is auto number field on account, I want to rename it. And I cannot seem to find this field to rename in Rename tabs and label setup menu. Please suggest.

If you are referring `AccountNumber` though it is text field, or any other Standard fields then that label can also be changed upon going through the next screen.

For custom field label change, you have to use translation workbench.

Comment: Thank you for your help on the first query. The second one though is not a text field. It is a custom auto number field. any idea how to rename this.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the auto number field

Comment: For custom field label change, you have to use translation workbench.